# Is there a faster way to convert snippet in vim-snippet to UltiSnips format?

Tags: vim, format, code-snippets

Today I try to use Ultisnips and I know vim-snippets provide a lot of snippets in many languages

But I have issues with converting from vim-snippets to UtilSnips

Here is one of c-snippets in vim-snippets :

```
# main(void)
snippet mainn
    int main(void)
    {
        ${0}
        return 0;
    }
```

And here is the snippet format in UtilSnips:

```
snippet Tab_trigger "Description" b

endsnippet
```

The two formats are different. If I have to convert manually, it will waste time with a large amount of snippet.

So I want to ask some ways to convert it cleaner and faster than manually?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing "vim-snippets" with "snipMate": Vim-snippets is a collection of snippets for both SnipMate *and* UltiSnips, with the snippet you show being a *snipMate* one.

And you are making a mountain of a molehill. Converting a snippet from one format to the other is, at worst, a tiny bit more involved than a yank/put, especially considering that you are using the most awesome text editor ever:

```
snippet mainn
int main(void)
{
    ${VISUAL}$0
    return 0;
}
endsnippet
```

Also, as said earlier, vim-snippet already provides lots of UltiSnips snippets so "large amount" is a bit of an overstatement: with 56 snippets in `snippets/c.snippets` and 17 snippets in `UltiSnips/c.snippets`, you are looking at ~10 minutes of work, including opening a PR so that others can benefit from your hard work.

Comment: What do you mean when you said PR ???

Comment: [Pull Request](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/pulls)